# Especificar colunas em um relacionamento com Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-eloquent

Tenho um relacionamento de `User` com `Role`.

```
User::with('role')->get()
```

No caso, `User` tem as colunas: `id`, `name,` `role_id`, `created_at` e `updated_at`.

E Role tem: `id`, `name`, `slug`, `created_at`, `updated_at`.

Como faço pra selecionar apenas name de `Role` ?

Como eu faria para especificar colunas específicas desse relacionamento ?

Comment: Pergunta feita pelo app no celular

Comment: Fez a pergunta no ônibus ?

Comment: Sim, no ônibus, kkkkkkk

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No model `User` na função de relacionamento `role()` você pode fazer `select()`.

```
public function role(){
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Role')->select('name', 'id');
}
```

Outra opção:

```
User::select('role_id', 'name')->with('role', function($query){
    $query->select('id', 'name');
})
->get();
```

Comment: Olha, isso resolve o problema, mas particurlarmente, para não ficar com hard code, eu prefiro o `with` com `Closure`.

Answer (score 1):

Em complemento à resposta do [@DiegoSouza](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/23919), é possível fazer isso através do `with` usando o nome do relacionamento como `chave` e a `Closure` como valor.

Veja:

```
$with['role'] = function ($query) {
   $query->select('id', 'name');
};

User::with($with)->get();
```

Importante notar que, na pergunta foi pedido para selecionar apenas o campo `name` de `Role`, porém o Laravel faz o relacionamento dos dados internamente usando o valor definido em `Model::getKey()` (no caso o `id`) de `Role`.

Então, sempre que foi fazer uma `select` em um relacionamento, é necessário selecionas os campos onde o Laravel vai atribuir os valores.

Um segundo exemplo:

```
$with['role'] = function ($query) {
   $query->select('id', 'name');
};

 User::select('name', 'role_id')->with($with)->get();
```

Nesse segundo exemplo, eu precisaria selecionar também `role_id`, caso fosse fazer a escolha dos campos de `User`, já que internamente o Laravel relacionará `User::$role_id` com `Role::$id`;